# Independable or undependable, which is correct?

Tags: single-word-requests

Both independable and undependable are present in dictionaries, can I use them interchangeably? Which is the more common spelling?

Usage example:

> she proves that this claim is independable / undependable.

Answer (score 1):

*Undependable* is the main word. Major dictionaries do also list *independable*, redirecting to *undependable*, but if you look at the [frequency of their usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independable%2C+undependable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindependable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cundependable%3B%2Cc0), you'll see that *independable* is very rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

They are [both correct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/independable), ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independable%2Cundependable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindependable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cundependable%3B%2Cc0)*** shows a clear preference for ***[undependable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/undependable)***  from the early 20th century.

(M-W, ODO)